# Equivalent 'spread' and 'gather' in R/tidyverse in python/pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

for example.
Data A:

```
y female male
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

I want to 'gather' it to this:

```
y gender value
1 female 2
1 male 3
4 female 5
4 male 6
```

It's easy in R. What about python pandas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should try melt , in the given data , the opposite(spread version is called cast), these melt and cast functions are very similar to R's reshape2:

```
import pandas as pd    
pd.melt(dt, id_vars="y")
```

Where dt is your input table

**Output**:

```
#y  variable      value
#1  female          2
#4  female          5
#1  male            3
#4  male            6
```

Comment: I've got you. But there is still a problem. Assume there are many variables: x1, x2...x50, y1, y2. Then I gather y1  and y2 into a column. The code is: pd.melt(dt, id_vars=['x1','x2'...'x50'],value_vars=['y1','y2']. There are too many inputs to id_vars, it's not like this in R. Do you have a more comfortable way to input id_vars?

Comment: @Bin You can do everything with melt and cast, these are old functions, request you to ask everything when you ask a question, also as suggested if your problem is performance in R use data.table. see this link: https://seananderson.ca/2013/10/19/reshape/ and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.melt.html, also youdon't have to type that, you can save column names using df.columns.tolist() to save it into separete object and do the operation

Answer (score 3):

**Gather**

```
df1=df.melt(id_vars='y')
df1
```

**Spread**

```
df2=df1.pivot(index='y', columns='variable')
df2
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```py
from datar import f
from datar.tibble import tribble
from datar.tidyr import pivot_longer

df = tribble(
  f.y, f.female, f.male,
  1,   2,        3,
  4,   5,        6
)

pivot_longer(df, [f.female, f.male], names_to="gender")

#    y    name  value
# 0  1  female      2
# 1  4  female      5
# 2  1    male      3
# 3  4    male      6
```

I am the author of the [datar](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Please feel free to submit issues if you have any questions about using it.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the ***melt*** from the pandas (pd.melt).

Use ***id_vars*** to define your main gather/melt variable; ***value_vars*** to define your value variables; ***var_name*** to define the titles of your value-vars variables; and ***value_name*** to define the title of your actual values.

Look at this example:

```
#Import pandas module
import pandas as pd

# Define the dataframe
DF = pd.DataFrame({'y': [1,4], 'female': [2,5], 'male': [3,6]})

# Gather/melt the data frame
pd.melt(DF, id_vars='y', value_vars=['female', 'male'],var_name='gender',
value_name='value')
```

That is how your output looks like:

```
    y   gender  value
0   1   female  2
1   4   female  5
2   1   male    3
3   4   male    6
```